# Noted instances of Kares and Ariri

Tags: history, karet

Are there any written recordings in any branch of Torah where we find a comment proving someone actually died from Kares/Ariri?

Now, of course being a heavenly decree it would be hard to know for sure, but do we find a statement even assuming that this was the case?

Cases where Hashem is said to have been upset and punished someone for a given action, such as Er and Onan, is not what I am looking for, being pre-Har Sinai, and also seemingly not working within the broader, generalized rules.

What I am looking for is a statement along the lines of this person did this forbidden act for which the Torah says one receives kares, and this person actually died from kares.

Midrash and Aggad'ta welcome.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "not working within the broader, generalized rules". +1, though: interesting question.

Comment: @msh210 weren't they minors? And the psukim seem to imply there was a specialized intervention of Hashem, not working within a standard framework.

Comment: @msh210 ty. The impetus was thinking about why we don't see Kares nowadays, which led to thinking, well, when did we?